# Find out what programs are heavily using the network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireshark

Currently, I have a process on my Windows 7 system which is saturating the incoming broadband internet connection (75Mbit/s) and almost completely saturating the 100Mbit network controller.

I cannot for the life of me locate this process. I have terminated all the suspect programs and it continues. I'm wondering if it's some kind of Windows update or other download, but I don't know. I've done everything short of rebooting to kill it (I'd like to avoid this as I am performing a uninterruptable calculation simultaneously.)

Is there a command available under Windows 7 (Ultimate x64) that will allow me to see which process is using most of the network? I'm aware of `netstat -b`, but that doesn't give statistics on data rates. I've also tried Wireshark, but again, I can't seem to find a simple "process:data rate" listing. Notably, starting Wireshark drops the data rate to 60Mbit/s, presumably because of how many packets it is analysing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

step1: goto Resource Monitor

[image: goto Resource Monitor]

Then press on the network TAB

[image: http://puu.sh/4pLrn.png]

Is that what you're looking for?