# how to see all network requests made by an application

Tags: windows, networking, process, wireshark, network-protocols

Suppose i have an application running abc.exe, how to see all the network requests made by this application?
Wireshark is good to see all the requests from the pc, but is there any filter for requests from particular application.
 
The requests made by abc.exe can be of any type, http, https, or just LAN pings.
Is there any way to do it apart from seeing all network requests, just for an application.

For example: how we use charles for firefox, like that anything available?
Thanks.

**EDIT**: From using smartsniff i understood that we can't have single requests sent by an application.
Only browsers do that, send a request line and get a response. 
So most applications open an address and port & starts reading/writing from/into it.
So how to trace them for an *particular application*?

Comment: please take some effort to search for questions before asking the same question. dup -> http://superuser.com/questions/644617/find-out-what-programs-are-heavily-using-the-network/644621#644621

Comment: i searched for almost an hour.. i guess the question u referred & mine didnt have common keywords. anyway thanks :) EDIT: no no ...that is not at all what i am asking for. the question u referred is seeing the processes which are using networks, i am asking requests sent by a application

Answer (score 2):

You could try [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) from NirSoft. This should give process information by enabling the 'Retrieve process information while capturing packets' option in the 'Advanced Options' window and then showing the relevant columns. See [here](http://blog.nirsoft.net/2010/09/20/how-to-use-smartsniff-to-view-general-tcp-connections-activity/) for more details. Having said that, I couldn't get it to work, but you may have more luck.

Comment: Please add more details of the procedure in you answer.